# Android Room - Interface as Entity

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview, android-room, adapter

I have an interface that contains object types. It is also used for ViewTypes.

```
public interface EventType {
    int TYPE_FROG = 1;
    int TYPE_STEAK = 2;
    int TYPE_ELEPHANT = 3;

    int getType();

    void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder);
}
```

And also I have three classes of data - Frog, Elephant and Steak.
I display an array of all these objects on the screen.

```
@Entity
public class Frog implements EventType {

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;

    String title;

    Boolean isCompleted;

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return EventType.TYPE_FROG;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        ViewHolderFactory.FrogViewHolder frogViewHolder = (ViewHolderFactory.FrogViewHolder) viewHolder;
        frogViewHolder.tv.setText("Жаба");
    }
}

@Entity
public class Elephant extends Frog implements EventType{

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;

    String title;

    Boolean isCompleted;

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return EventType.TYPE_ELEPHANT;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        ViewHolderFactory.ElephantViewHolder elephantViewHolder = (ViewHolderFactory.ElephantViewHolder) viewHolder;
        elephantViewHolder.tv.setText("Слон");
    }
}

@Entity
public class Steak extends Frog implements EventType{

    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    int id;

    String title;

    Boolean isCompleted;


    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return EventType.TYPE_STEAK;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder) {
        ViewHolderFactory.SteakViewHolder steakViewHolder = (ViewHolderFactory.SteakViewHolder) viewHolder;
        steakViewHolder.tv.setText("Стейк");
    }
}
```

in my fragment I create a list of objects of all three types, i.e. List.
List displayed in RecyclerView using an adapter.

How can I save this List to the database? Or do I have to create a separate table from the interface?

Comment: why you wana mix DAO with UI object ? You shouldn't do this ... use one entity and add type field

Comment: What should I do? I don't quite understand.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a single `Entity` (so one table) to store them all. You can then have the `type` as a field and use that to map the objects returned from the database into the correct type for your presentation layer.

So your entity would be something like this:

```
DatabaseEntity(int id, int type, String title, boolean isCompleted)
```

Then you would map that to the correct object based upon its type, so:

```
EventType map(DatabaseEntity entity) {

    if(entity.type == TYPE_FROG) {
        
        return new Frog(...);
    }
}
```

This is obviously all just pseudocode, you should implement it in a way that makes the most sense to you. However you generally shouldn't mix your database models with the models in your presentation layer. Even though it's simpler to have a single model, it generally causes more headaches further down the line, as in your example.

Comment: Also I have to know... What type of app has a mix of frogs, elephants and steaks?!

Comment: These are all types of events according to the time-management system)